# How to get values for an object before save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model-view-controller, model

Could you tell me please how can I get data for an object that is changed.

For example, I have an object `@student = {:name => 'xxx', :class => 'yyy'}` and a user plays with this object on the site. After the object is saved I notify user about what has been changed, for example, `Student #{@student.name} has changed #{@student.class}`.

So basically how to get previous data from a model that was there before save?

*Note:* `before_save` callback doesn't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`paper_trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) gem which allows versioning of and tracking changes on your models.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActiveRecord's [`changed`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/changed) method and persist the results in the flash before completing the save.

```
flash[:changed_attrs] = @student.changed.join(', ')
```